# Is there a way to identify where NAs are introduced?

Tags: r, na, gsub, coercion

Recently went through my fairly large dataset and realized some foo decided to use commas. Trying to convert it all to numeric. Used a nice little gsub to get rid of those pesky commas, but I'm still finding NAs introduced by coercion. Is there a way to identify the location by column and row where those NAs are being introduced so I can see why that is occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `is.na()` function.  Consider the following data frame, which contains `NA` values, as an example:

```
> df <- data.frame(v1=c(1,2,NA,4), v2=c(NA,6,7,8), v3=c(9,NA,NA,12))
> df
  v1 v2 v3
1  1 NA  9
2  2  6 NA
3 NA  7 NA
4  4  8 12
```

You can use `is.na` along with `sapply` to get the following result:

```
> sapply(df, function(x) { c(1:length(x))[is.na(x)] })
$v1
[1] 3

$v2
[1] 1

$v3
[1] 2 3
```

Each column will come back along with the rows where `NA` values occurred.

Comment: In a very large dataset, is there a way to do an is.na that would identify the column and row of NAs instead of trying to sort through that whole list of true and false?

Comment: I also note that some of the responses list integer(0) as the response. Could you help me clarify what that means in this context?

Comment: @BenjaminBaker - it means no NA's were found in that column. What is returned is an empty integer vector, with no data stored.

Answer (score 1):

I would also use `which` with `arr.ind=TRUE` to get the row/column indices ('df' from @Tim Biegeleisen's post)

```
 which(is.na(df), arr.ind=TRUE)
 #     row col
 #[1,]   3   1
 #[2,]   1   2
 #[3,]   2   3
 #[4,]   3   3
```